# Which 2d barcode has the highest data capacity/density

Tags: encoding, binary, compression, qr-code

;)

if you wanted encode  2mb of data  onto a 2d-bar code, which 2-bar code would be good to starting point or recommend.

There are lots and different types of 2dbar codes out today,Aztec 2-d barcodes,maxicodes,Pdf417,Microsoft HCCB,vericodes....etc...lots.... all unique in their own way.

**i guess in a nutshell my questions is....  which barcode would make a good start off point to encode 2mb of data??**

i  tried reading through the Qr code international standard turns out even @ version 40L the most amount of data you could encode is on to a Qr code is

1) numeric data: 7 089 characters

2) alphanumeric data: 4 296 characters

3) 8-bit byte data: 2 953 characters

4) Kanji data: 1 817 characters

**which are all  a far cry from the 17million bits thats is 2mb**

my goal was to create  something like

http://realestatemobilemarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/real-estate-mobile-marketing.png

**After you scan the barcode you can view photos of the house/property on your phone, you dont have to walk-in or wait for an open home,20 photos @ 100kb each is about 2mb**

Comment: The best way would be to create a mobile site with those 20 photos and then encode a link to that mobile friendly site.

Answer (score 7):

Even if you could create a single 2D barcode which will encode the whole thing, the user won't be able to scan the whole thing in one go. No one has a cellphone imager which will support that kind of resolution.  Your best bet is to do a QR-code with a URL in it.

Things like DataMatrix and QR-codes are extensible.  You have a limit to how much data can be encoded into one block, but you CAN create a code which has multiple blocks.  Indeed, if you look at [this page](http://www.ollydbg.de/Paperbak/index.html), you'll see a discussion of using pages full of 2D barcodes as a form of data backup.  They were able to fit up to 1/2 MByte of raw data into a single page.  That's at 600 dpi, which will require a scanner (not a smartphone) to decode.

From what I've been reading, DataMatrix tends to have less overhead and,  therefore, will stuff more (payload) data into a square inch for a given DPI.  You would need a mobile app capable of shooting multiple images (tiles) of a very large image and either:

- compositing the individual images into one large one for decoding OR
- decoding each of the smaller blocks and reconstructing the original data from the pieces

I know of no app which will do that.

I've pondered providing bulk data via 2D barcodes.  I was pondering publishing a mobile app in a magazine and providing a way for people to "download" the app from the magazine, without needing to provide a website / FTP site where they could download it.  I'd first need to provide an app which could decode such a monster.  Then, the end user would have to be patient enough to scan the whole thing.  Good luck with that.

I MIGHT be able to provide a large 2D barcode containing a .torrent file and then using existing BitTorrent apps to download the resulting app; I have a .torrent for a recent Linux Live-DVD where the .torrent is < 32 KB.

A chunk of data (an app or images) in the MB or larger range ... really not feasible through this channel.  The megabytes of data you're wanting to provide ... again ... really not feasible through this channel.

Answer (score 1):

Voiceye Code is the highest density 3d code I have been able to find. Works well too, but code making software is price prohibitive to screw around with. 500.00 (ish)

Answer (score 0):

How about using some variant of DataGlyphs, which has a lot in common with steganography?  In other words, you use a greyscale image to *also* store your data...

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a reader for JAB codes that can read whole audio file from a codebar. JAB codes are very high capacity due to polychrome nature.

More on this [here](https://hvitis.dev/jab-code-and-everything-you-need-to-know-about-color-bar-code)

Answer (score 0):

lol you don't have to encode a picture (images of property) to a picture (qr code of image) for others to view an open home. Instead of scanning a qr code to see a picture, viewers can just see the picture on whatever media the code would have been printed.

The size of the qr code image would probably be bigger than the image of the house for a good resolution of the image.

QR code was developed for automation eg. sorting parcels, similar to punch card readers from the past millennium which bypassed human involvement, thereby speeding up process work. It requires less programming than OCR software and smaller footprint (memory/storage/processor).

In your case, the property images would be viewed by people, who can just see the property instead of seeing a QR code to be scanned to see the images. The idea is good though, scanning data directly instead of scanning a link to data held on some server, requiring network connection to the server. In programming, a similar concept is passing data by value instead of reference.

One possible solution would be to make a scanner that can read a matrix of QR codes, and decode. Another would be to scan a QR code, store, then scan next code, and when all codes have been scanned and stored in device, decode, similar to reading pages in a book, to make sense of the whole book, like this [multi code scanner](https://www.dynamsoft.com/blog/insights/scan-multiple-barcodes-and-qr-codes-at-once/).

Another possible solution, to increase data density is to add a parallel dimension eg. [colored QR code](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301788314_Region_Identification_and_Decoding_Of_Security_Markers_Using_Image_Processing_Tools), or different shapes similar to concept in [Grid Matrix Code](https://barcodeguide.seagullscientific.com/Content/Symbologies/Grid_Matrix.htm).

A [hologram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography) could also store multiple codes in the same image, to be scanned from different angles, for different 'pages'.

For pictures, since there are only 95 printable characters in ASCII, QR can be generated after some sort of image encoding eg. base64, making the space requirement much larger than the original 256 bit image. QR code is based on printable characters.

[Voiceye code](http://voiceye-app.com/) is able to store 250,000 characters, and so far is the highest density 2D code.